# Read and write rows from user-supplied Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, google-docs-api

I've got a tiny Jquery Mobile App I use to learn music more efficiently.  (You're welcome to use it, too, but be aware it's very much alpha-ware at this time.)  All the logic is in the javascript that's served with the page, i.e. there's presently no backend at all -- it's served from a Google Drive hosted page mapped to a domain I own.

The current version of the app is at http://soup.ellisandgrant.com

I'd like to extend it to do some simple record-keeping by allowing users to supply a link to a Google Sheet that will hold rows recording the tune name, date, elapsed practice time, etc for each session.  I'm very much looking for a '*simplest thing that could possibly work*' approach because I don't see this becoming a commercial product.  It's mostly for my own use and anyone else who's crazy enough to practice the way I do :-)

I realize that HTML5 provides some capabilities for local storage, but I've ruled that out since I use the app from more than one device and expect others might want to do the same.  My thought is to use local storage only for the user's sheet URL to avoid having to enter it more than once.

What I'm looking for is some Jquery/js sample code (or a link thereto) that shows how to

1. Connect to the sheet and read rows into a 2-D array, and
2. Append a new row from a 1-D array.

Thanks!

Comment: I must have done a terrible job of framing this question. First time I've ever had a question go more than 24 hours with zero responses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more than a handful of lines of Javascript. You need to understand Google OAuth and Spreadsheet API, neither of which are trivial.

One possible approach is to create a spreadsheet form, reverse engineer it, and POST from your app to the form. Google were trying to deprecate this approach, but I believe it still works.